# Open cart gateway time out after backup restore

Tags: opencart

I have opencart 3.0.3.8 installed and PLesk Obsdian and ubuntu-20.04-x86_64..

whenever I try to restore a plesk backup the site stops working and generates a gateway timeout error even though the admin panel still works! even after deleting the whole domain and recreating it.. even after uploading the files and database manually,  still gives gateway time out!!

I looked all over the internet for a solution in vain! this happened to me many times and it's very annoying!

please any help?

Comment: Plesk has a great forum for such questions. Maybe an expert on there can help you solve it? It'll be https://talk.plesk.com